# cq: Remove cq:LiveRelationship mixin recursivly

Tags: aem, day-cq

i've copied a complete Website within CQ.
Now i have the mixin cq:LIveRelationship on every Site. I tried to detach it with the MultiSiteManager but it doesn't bring me the detach Option for this site.
The only way to remove this Status is to detach the mixin for every site.
Is there a possiblity to remove the mixin for a complete "Folder" recursive?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the Bulk Editor to remove the mixin from the pages.  You can certainly search on a type/mixin.  You may be able to remove the mixin property also.

See [The Bulk Editor - Searching & Editing Content](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/administering/bulk_editor.html#Searching and Editing Content).

If the pages you are updating have a at most a single mixin, you maybe able to delete the jcr:mixinTypes property.  If there are other mixins, they you may need to walk the tree and remove the mixins on the nodes.